# Python Dataframe Groupby Mean and STD

Tags: python, dataframe, numpy, pandas-groupby, mean

I know how to compute the groupby mean or std. But now I want to compute both at a time.
My code:

```
df = 
   a      b      c      d
0  Apple  3      5      7
1  Banana 4      4      8
2  Cherry 7      1      3
3  Apple  3      4      7

xdf = df.groupby('a').agg([np.mean(),np.std()])
```

Present output:

```
TypeError: _mean_dispatcher() missing 1 required positional argument: 'a'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to remove `()` from the `np.` functions:

```py
xdf = df.groupby("a").agg([np.mean, np.std])
print(xdf)
```

Prints:

```
          b         c              d     
       mean  std mean       std mean  std
a                                        
Apple     3  0.0  4.5  0.707107    7  0.0
Banana    4  NaN  4.0       NaN    8  NaN
Cherry    7  NaN  1.0       NaN    3  NaN
```

---

EDIT: To "flatten" column multi-index:

```py
xdf = df.groupby("a").agg([np.mean, np.std])
xdf.columns = xdf.columns.map("_".join)
print(xdf)
```

Prints:

```
        b_mean  b_std  c_mean     c_std  d_mean  d_std
a                                                     
Apple        3    0.0     4.5  0.707107       7    0.0
Banana       4    NaN     4.0       NaN       8    NaN
Cherry       7    NaN     1.0       NaN       3    NaN
```

Comment: How do I rename the columns say `b_mean`, `b_std`, etc?

Comment: Really great solution. Thanks