# Making a mean-SD distribution graph of a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, graph

My objective is to create a mean-SD distribution plot from a `pandas` DataFrame, similarly to the following image:

[image]

I have a mass DataFrame `df`:

```
Time          Variable
1             -0.13   
1             0.24
1             -0.09
...
100           0.05
100           0.41
100           -0.17
```

and as `df` is large, I want to graph some samples of `df` rather than the entire dataset. For instance, I decided to sample 500 data points:

```
df_array = df.to_numpy()

sample_size = 500
rand_index = np.random.randint(len(df_array),size=sample_size)
sample = df_array[rand_index,:]
```

Then, I would have to calculate mean and standard deviation for each `Time` and graph them. I attempted the following:

```
## Compute the sample average and std
sample_mean = np.mean(sample,axis=0)
sample_sd = np.std(sample,axis=0)

## Plot the sample average and std
plt.plot(range(2),sample_mean,"-",label="Mean")
plt.fill_between(
    range(2),
    sample_mean-sample_sd,
    sample_mean+sample_sd,
    alpha=0.4,
    color="C0",
    edgecolor="none",
    label=r"$1\sigma$")
plt.xlabel("Time")
plt.ylabel("Variable")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

but this is obviously wrong, as the code takes the mean and SD of the entire array, not per `Time` value. Is there a way to store all the mean and SD values of `Time` variables so that plotting the desired graph is feasible?

Comment: What is the shape of your variable `sample`?
Is it `(number_of_time_units, N)` and you need the mean and std along the second dimension?

Comment: @lifezbeautiful it is (500,2): 2 from the number of columns, and 500 sample size.

Comment: and you want the mean and std for each of those 2 values? right?

Comment: @lifezbeautiful as I sample 500 data points, I want the mean and std of `Variable` for each unique `Time`, so that I can create a graph that looks like the one in the post

Comment: In that case, you do not know how many samples you will have for each time step right? Hence, you can't simply take the mean over numpy array.  You will need to use [df.groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) `Time` on your sample and get the mean and  std from there. Thereafter you can proceed with the plotting. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68089243/3896008) answer demonstrates the usage clearly